# how get payload in int-http:outbound-gateway in call to rest/json service

Tags: spring-integration

From a channel with a payload call to 
one int-http:outbound-gateway that call to an url to returns a JSON response

How get the initial payload from caller to get the initial payload,
i´d need it to use in aggregator

This is the scene

message --> channel --> service activator --> outputchannel

outputchannel--->int-http:outbound-gateway(call rest service1) -->response to *

outputchannel--->int-http:outbound-gateway(call rest service2) -->response to *

- aggregator

Answer (score 1):

You should place it to the `MessageHeaders`:

```
<header-enricher>
   <header name="requestPayload" expression="payload"/>
</header-enricher>
```

before those `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` invocation and extract it from headers in the `aggregator` logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot.i found this !!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998217/spring-integration-how-to-keep-the-orginal-payload-and-use-it-later?rq=1

Comment: Good to know. So, it sounds like acceptance for the answer.